# Return data in lightswitch only after search

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm dipping my toes into the lightswitch arena and am trying to rewrite an application that they want to keep similar to its roots, to prevent too much user headaches, and the first screen is a simple database search. You have several fields you can search on and then you click search.

In lightswitch, it seems you have to return a data list/grid/table first and then do the search. Is there anyway to prevent the data from coming in until after you do the search on the criteria? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to do this for a Silverlight client, you could turn off the "Auto Execute Query" setting for the collection.  This basically prevents the runtime from automatically executing the query in which case you are responsible for writing the code necessary to execute the query at the appropriate time(s).  See this page for more info (search for "Auto Executing Queries"): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/05/29/lightswitch-tips-amp-tricks-on-query-performance.aspx.

If this is for an HTML client, it doesn't look like there's support for turning off the Auto Execute Query functionality.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ba5bc5f-b3fe-44d3-a7e8-67d924b7772d/html-client-autoexecute-query.

Comment: It's for the HTML client. :/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a table/grid view, you would be adding in a query, within that you add a filter, for example:

```
Where |  FirstName | contains | (Parameter) | (Search)

Parameter | Search | of type | String | is optional
```

this by default would only work when the user presses enter after they typed in there search value...

in the Parameter options there is a box 'Is Optional' you can check which makes this optional, so all the results are displayed before you search, and additionally when not checked, the search criteria must be entered first..

I think this is what your after, if not give me an idea and ill try and help :)